# TensorFlow v1 on Colab, tf.contrib module not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Trying to train GPT-2 in Google Colab. The cells I'm running look like this:

```py
!git clone https://github.com/shawwn/gpt-2 -b tpu /content/gpt-2
```

[...]

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
!pip freeze | grep tensorflow
```

> ```
> mesh-tensorflow==0.1.12
> tensorflow==1.15.2
> tensorflow-datasets==4.0.1
> tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
> tensorflow-gan==2.0.0
> tensorflow-gcs-config==2.4.0
> tensorflow-hub==0.11.0
> tensorflow-metadata==0.28.0
> tensorflow-probability==0.7.0
> ```

```py
%tensorflow_version 1.x
!PYTHONPATH=src ./train.py --help
```

I get the following error message:

```
TensorFlow 1.x selected.
2021-03-14 14:22:11.118915: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./train.py", line 17, in <module>
    import model, sample, encoder
  File "/content/gpt-2/src/model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.training import HParams
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

As far as I know, TensorFlow v1.15.2 should contain the contrib module. What am I doing wrong here?

Note that I did not write this code, I'm using someone else's git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1.15.2 has contrib.
In colab, make sure once the Tensorflow 1.x install restart runtime because colab has default 2.x version.
I tried same code on colab it worked.

Comment: Even after I restart the runtime, it doesn't work.